# Get AD attributes of members of a group using PHP LDAP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm using PHP to query Active Directory. I need to get a few attributes (Office phone and email) of all the members of a specified group.

I can get the complete CNs of the users in the group, so, for example:

```
        $results = ldap_search($ds,$ldapbase, "cn=" . $group);
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ds, $results);
        $members = $entries[0]['member'];

            for ($i=0; $i< count($members) -1; $i++) {

                $mem = $members[$i];

                if($mem != "") {

                    $groupMembers[] = $mem;
                }
            }
```

will give me an array of  members of the group like this:

```
 CN=Testlastname1\, Testfirstname1,OU=Personnel,OU=All Staff,DC=domain,DC=domainsuffix              
 CN=Testlastname2\, Testfirstname2,OU=All Staff,DC=domain,DC=domainsuffix               
 etc...
```

My question, how can I take these results and query the attributes I need, namely the officephone and email address for each one? Or am I going at it completely wrong?

I have seen some things close to this and some (somewhat byzantine) examples that I cannot get to work. I have played with various filter syntax to no avail. There must be a way to take the individual results from the successful group query, retrieve the AD object described by the result, and extract the properties required, but I have yet to find it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

BTW - PHP Version 5.5.7 using FastCGI on Windows 2008R2, IIS7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work somehow:

```
foreach ($groupsmembers as $groupmember) {
    $result = ldap_search($ds,$groupmember, '*', 'officephone,mail');
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ds, $results);
    $users[$groupmember]['officephone'] = $entries[0]['officephone'][0];
    $users[$groupmember]['mail'] = $entries[0]['mail'][0];
}
```

Main thing is, that you use the retrieved DN (which is the thingy with `CN=Testlastname1\, Testfirstname1,OU=Personnel,OU=All Staff,DC=domai....`) as search-base and then retrieve the email and officephone-attributes from it.

On the (Linux)-Commandline that would look like this:

```
ldapsearch -h ldap-server -b "CN=Testlastname1, Testfirstname1,OU=Personnel,OU=All Staff,DC=domain,DC=domainsuffix" * mail,officephone
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'll have a go in a few hours and let you know.

Comment: Good advice. What I ended up doing is parsing the individual result using ldap_explode_dn, taking the first value [0] and searching for it -- $filter = "(&(CN=$parsedresult[0]))". This worked and is more or less what you suggested.

Comment: More efficient is to search for users who are members of a group, rather than searching for a group, getting its `member` property and then doing individual search for all members. The following search filter should do the trick:
`(&(objectCategory=Person)(memberOf=GROUP_DN_HERE))`

Comment: Yes, you are right @RobertRossmann. But that only works when there is a memberOf-attribute set in the user-entry. There are LDAP-schemes out there that have the group members set via a uniqueMember-attribute in the group-entry.  Then you have no other choice than itterating through these entries. So it depends on the individual setup.

Comment: @heiglandreas  - How can I tell in AD if the uniqueMember attribute is set?

Comment: You can use an LDAP-tool like jXplorer to connect to your LDAP and inspect the nodes and their attributes. That way you can see whether the attribute is set.