# Get Ldap group names with the group Type

Tags: php, ldap

[LDAP group type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD2Jp.png)

Hello everyone,
I am new to the LDAP, active directoy. I am working on a php function which is collecting all the groups from active directory and saving it in DB. I am able to get the group names but now I need to add group type to DB as well. To get the ldap group names I used ldap_get_entries function but I would like to know how can I get the group type? Is there any function where I can pass the group name and get the type? If anyone can just guide me in correct direction or any helpful tip will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `ldap_get_attributes`? See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26163489/18667225). If you still have difficulties please share your code! [ask]